# ORDS_INTERNAL package can not be compiled during/after ORDS 19.0.4 installtion

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-apex, oracle-rest-data-services

In one of our oracle 11g databases we get following error during ORDS 19.4.0 installation.

[*** script: ords_internal.plb]

```
Package Body ORDS_INTERNAL compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
129/7     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
134/9     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

because package source is wrapped we couldn't get the name of the object that causes this error.

What can I  resolve or get the know why I get this error?

Comment: Did you run the script `/path/to/installer/ords_installer_privileges.sql` ? What is the procedure you are using to install ORDS ?

Comment: I installed by following the usual way.   "java -jar ords.war install advanced" with SYS user

Answer (score 0):

okay we  have solved this. first we checked the status of all used objects by ORDS_INTERNAL package body and found no object that is INVALID. Then check the grants of all dependencies and see that someone/somebody has removed the SELECT grant on ALL_USERS from PUBLIC.
fixing  (grant select on sys.ALL_USERS to public) this issue resolved our compilation problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think that because of you are using Oracle 11g as database, you must run the script mentioned by @pifor

Here is what Oracle doc says

**Starting with ORDS 19.2 release, the Oracle REST Data Services installation archive file contains a script, ords_installer_privileges.sql which is located in the installer folder. The script provides the assigned database user the privileges to install, upgrade, validate and uninstall ORDS in Oracle Pluggable Database or Oracle 11g.**

So, please run this

Connect to your Oracle 11g database with SYSDBA privileges.
Execute the following script providing the database user that is going to use ORDS

```
SQL> @/path/to/installer/ords_installer_privileges.sql exampleuser
```

I think it would have been less problematic if you have selected a older version of ORDS, as you have a very old database version.

Regards

Comment: As I know, this script is used when you don't want to use SYS for installation. If you want to use another user for installing ORDS you give grants to that user with this ords_installer_privileges.sql. thanks